# Finding a value in a serialized model array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, serialization, models

I am not sure if an explanation is already documented on this, maybe im asking the wrong question, but i hope someone can help me with this issue.

I am looking for a value within a model array.  My model looks like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    #  product_category    :text
    serialize :product_category, Array
end
```

An example of an entry:

```
#<Product:0x0055cd0c1382b8> {
       :id => 42266,
       :product_category => [
           [0] 8, [1] 3
       ]
}
```

I need to find all products that belong to `product_category` 3 or a combination of 3 and other categories.

I tried something like

```
ap Product.where(product_category: [8])
```

but this doesnt return anything.

If this question was already asked, please forward me to the right answer. If not, any time put towards helping me is greatly appreciated.

Running:

- Rails 4.2.4
- Ruby 2.3.1.p112
- SQLite3

Comment: It seems like you should restructure your database and use a `has_and_belongs_to_many` or `has_many :through` with product categories rather than serialize a product category column.  This would make it easier to search

Comment: Lookup by serialized field is impossible. You should restructure your database as @j-dexx suggested.

Comment: What Database are you using? What type is the column. If you are using JSON style column in Postgres, then you can query for array contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I would not recommend to do this, but a patch work would be as follows

```
Product.all.select { |m| m.product_category.include? '3' }
```

Don't use #serialize for any data that later on you need to query

Comment: This seems to work, but as you and other suggest I will restructure my database instead. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: There is no such need to restructure it if you dont have much queries . You can use where clause to overcome the performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is through where clause

```
Product.where("product_category = ?", [3].to_yaml)
```

.to_yaml will do the trick.